# External Global Variable Definition for VBA Projects

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Have been developing a long time in VBA but as a first year associate in CIB, I'm seeing a pattern in variable definition I wish to address. I work with a list of files, i.e. tech_yyyymmdd.csv, bank_yyyymmdd.csv. They are stored within a directory which also has date variables.

My current problem is having to redefine these variables over and over again depending on the report I'm building. Sometimes I use 2 files, sometimes, I use 20. So I'm wondering if there is a way to import the **variable file names** from a single source. This would also make it easy to add a totally new file when one gets added.

I guess I could build a file, then have it load on open with the formulas defined. My first attempt was through PowerShell. The problem was that 90% of the time, we run for yesterday's date and I couldn't solve for a function take could also take a date variable outside of =Today().

Notes: I do not own these files, so I can't just throw them in one folder and iterate over them. That is possible for a few files but not all.

Power Query Solutions with VBA have not yielded positive results when reports are used by multiple people and even though I really like Power Query, it has generally given me more issues because I'm working with heavy data sets. I've raised issue in [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/power-query-renames-queries-with-a-2-and-fails-to/ea939f5b-e92d-4396-9dcd-9d2a4cb5c4e8).

Example of directory:
G:\Department\Sub-Deb\ProcessName\*year*\*mm-mmm*\*yyymmdd*\*filename*

When the code runs, it will pick up each file I need by using the .Range(namedrange) or .Range("A2"), etc.

I wish I could say that I have access to a database, even if I had to setup an ETL process myself but attempts at setting something up more robust are not classified as priority within my business unit. That being said, I am forced to support my own initiatives any way I can.

Comment: It's not clear how your code is working with the files, and where the file names are coming from. If there's a folder where the files are, why not define a constant for that folder, and iterate the files in it, instead of hard-coding what files you want? Also, it's unclear what a "date variable" might be referring to in the context of a directory. Please [edit] to clarify, show us the VBA code that defines these variables, for example.

Comment: Anyway I'd suggest to move the files you want to process into a specific folder, and have the VBA code only process whatever files are inside that folder (and move them into a "Processed" subfolder once done, or into a "Failed" subfolder when processing fails). Your source is the folder itself; you iterate the files in that folder, and there's no need to maintain or edit any list of global variables with any specific file names.

Comment: Another option is to work with Power Query (Data>Get Data>From) where, once programmed to work in a certain directory, every new CSV file placed there - or in some subdirectory - will already be part of the solution previously built, simply by opening the Workbook. Subsequently, in a Pivot Table, you can decide what is going to be shown.